# merge sort in k parts

Tags: java, sorting, mergesort

I'd really appreciate some help on this assignment.
The task is develop a merge sort algorithm that *"splits"* the input array recursively into k arrays. I initially coded two methods to merge sort with two parts, namely merge sort and merge. I tried to generalize this algorithm

```java
public class MergeSort {

    public static int[] mergeSort(int[] a, int p, int r) {
        // p is left bound
        // r is right bound
        if (p < r) {
            int q = (int)Math.floor((p + r) / 2);
            mergeSort(a, p, q);
            mergeSort(a, q + 1, r);
            return merge(a, p, q, r);
        } else
            return a;
    }

    // p ist linke grenze
    // r ist rechte grenze
    public static int[] merge(int[] a, int p, int q, int r) {
        int n1 = q - p + 1; //length of first array
        int n2 = r - q;     //length of second array
        int[] lt = new int[n1 + 1];
        int[] rt = new int[n2 + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
            lt[i] = a[p + i];
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
            rt[j] = a[q + j + 1];
        }
        lt[n1] = 1000000000; //sentinels
        rt[n2] = 1000000000;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        for (int k = p; k <= r; k++) { //comparing the values of the arrays and merging
            if (lt[i] <= rt[j]) {
                a[k] = lt[i];
                i++;
            } else {
                a[k] = rt[j];
                j++;
            }
        }
        return a;
    }

    public static int[] mergeSortK(int[] a, int k, int p, int r) {
        // k number of steps; p is first index of array; r is last index of array;
        if (p < r) {
            int[] pos = new int[k + 1]; //array for saving the indices of the "splits"
            for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
                pos[i] = (int) Math.floor(p + (r - p) / k * i); //saving the array indices
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
                mergeSortK(a, k, pos[i], pos[i + 1]); //sorting the arrays
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < k - 1; i++) {
                merge(a, pos[i], pos[i + 1], pos[i + 2]); //merging the arrays pairwise
            }
        }
        return a;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // task 2.1.a)
        // Example Values:
        int[] list = { 2, 1, 5, 6, 2, 12 };
        int k = 4;

        // use MergeSort
        int[] newlist = mergeSortK(list, k, 0, list.length);
        printList(newlist);
    }

    // Helper function to print the elements of a list
    private static void printList(int[] list) {
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(list[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The input given in the main method results in `{2, 1, 2, 5, 6, 12}`

Any help is immensely appreciated! Sorry if I'm doing some mistakes, I'm here to learn and I really hope you guys can help me out!

Comment: I think the idea is to split the array into k part on each split, before doing recursion. The k way merge will need to loop to find on of k runs with the smallest leading element, or use a minheap() (I don't know if you class has taught you minheap yet). You'll need a much larger list of numbers to test this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code:

- there is no need for `Math.floor()` to truncate the results of integer division, unlike Javascript, Java uses different semantics for `/` for `int` arguments and floating point arguments. `(p + r) / 2` is the integral quotient, But you might want to write `p + (r - p) / 2` to avoid potential overflow on `p + r`.
- the upper index is excluded as you pass `list.length` from `main()`. This is actually a very convenient convention to avoid the need for `+1` adjustments when computing slice sizes. Remove those erroneous adjustments and rely on the included/excluded convention.
- don't use sentinels: using sentinels prevents you from correctly sorting arrays containing values greater or equal to the sentinel value `1000000000`. This approach is not necessary and should be banned. Just compare the index variables to the slice lengths and copy the remaining elements when one of the slices is exhausted.
- your computation for the slice boundaries in `mergeSortK` is incorrect: `p + (r - p) / k * i` is computed with integer arithmetics so `(r - p) / k` is rounded before the multiplication. The last slice ending index will not equal `r` if `r - p` is not a multiple of `k`. Multiplying before the division would solve this issue but might overflow the range of type `int`.
- `mergeSortK` does not perform k-way merging, but a series of partial merges that are insufficient for `k > 2`.
- your test set is a bit small.

Here is a corrected version:

```java
public class MergeSort {

    public static int[] mergeSort(int[] a, int p, int r) {
        // p is left bound (included)
        // r is right bound (excluded)
        if (r - p >= 2) {
            int q = p - (r - p) / 2;
            mergeSort(a, p, q);
            mergeSort(a, q, r);
            return merge(a, p, q, r);
        } else {
            return a;
        }
    }

    // p is left bound (included)
    // q is start of right slice
    // r is end of right slice (excluded)
    public static int[] merge(int[] a, int p, int q, int r) {
        int n1 = q - p;  // length of first array
        int n2 = r - q;  // length of second array
        int[] lt = new int[n1];
        for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
            lt[i] = a[p + i];
        }
        int i = 0;  // index into lt
        int j = q;  // index into a for right slice
        int k = p;  // index into a for merged list

        while (i < n1 && j < r) { //comparing the values of the arrays and merging
            if (lt[i] <= a[j]) {
                a[k] = lt[i];
                i++;
                k++;
            } else {
                a[k] = a[j];
                j++;
                k++;
            }
        }
        while (i < n1) { // copy remaining elements from right slice
            a[k] = lt[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        // remaining elements from right slice are already in place
        return a;
    }

    public static int[] mergeSortK(int[] a, int k, int p, int r) {
        // k amount of steps; p is first index of slice; r is last index of slice (excluded);
        if (r - p >= 2) {
            if (k > r - p)
                k = r - p;
            int[] pos = new int[k + 1]; //array for saving the indices of the "splits"
            for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
                pos[i] = p + (r - p) * i / k; //saving the array indices
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
                mergeSortK(a, k, pos[i], pos[i + 1]); //sorting the arrays
            }
            while (k > 1) {
                int i, n = 1;
                for (i = 0; i < k - 1; i += 2) {
                    // merge slices 2 at a time: this will produce the expected output
                    //  but is not a direct k-way merge.
                    merge(a, pos[i], pos[i + 1], pos[i + 2]);
                    pos[n++] = pos[i + 2];
                }
                if (i < k)
                    pos[n++] = pos[i + 1];
                k = n - 1;
            }
        }
        return a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // task 2.1.a)
        // Example Values:
        int[] list = {
            64, 36, 46, 31, 45, 52,  4, 48, 74, 59,
            12, 16, 70, 67, 71, 26, 73, 34, 46, 84,
            60, 16, 26, 68, 56, 57, 97,  6, 39, 74,
            25, 69, 29, 69, 77, 26, 44, 53, 20,  6,
            77, 31, 71, 91, 28,  6, 24, 75, 26, 33,
             3, 20, 55, 94, 17, 81, 88, 32, 94, 32,
             3, 90, 76, 69,  9, 96, 76, 53, 78, 14,
            97, 32, 17, 15, 61, 63, 21,  0, 16, 14,
            61,  4, 81, 86, 29, 29, 27, 57, 85,  5,
            91, 54,  6, 68, 40, 88, 41,  9, 90, 51 };
        int k = 4;  // must be at least 2

        // use MergeSort
        int[] newlist = mergeSortK(list, k, 0, list.length);
        printList(newlist);
    }

    // Helper function to print the elements of a list
    private static void printList(int[] list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(list[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I did not write a correct k-way merging phase at the end of `mergeSortK`, the code above should work but will merge the k slices in ceil(log2(k)) passes. Direct one pass k-way merging is tricky and usually not worth it.

Comment: Direct one pass k-way merging is faster using if/else tree without using minheap. For bottom up merge sort, 4-way merge sort is about 15% faster than 2-way merge sort on a PC in 64 bit mode (16 registers) (the 4-way is a bit more cache friendly, more compares, fewer moves).

Comment: @rcgldr: direct one pass k-way merging with a variable k is not simple. Hardcoded 3-way or 4-way merging can be programmed efficiently as you say, but not generic k-way IMHO.

Comment: Assuming  1 <= k <= 4, it's not an issue, since 4 way has to transition into 3 way when the end of one of the 4 runs is reached, then to 2 way, then do copying the remainder of the remaining single run. For  k == 3 or 2, the code can just branch to the code that handles 3 way or 2 way. A minheap could be used for k > 4, then branch to 4 way once there are only 4 runs remaining. It probably means using goto's or switch case as an alternative to goto's.

Comment: Being able to avoid using minheap means that k == 4 will be faster than k > 4, unless the merge process is I/O bound, such as an external sort, in which case k == 16 is common.